# What is a good strategy for handling Complex Right Outer Joins in LINQ / EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have this Model

[image]

My goal is to retrieve all resources for a user except for resources that share a restricted role with that user.

This is not too hard in straight SQL (6BA60C09-2873-46A5-BAFB-5996A6C6482B is the userid)

```
SELECT distinct r.Name
FROM  dbo.Resources xr 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[x_Resource_RestrictedRole] rr ON  xr.Id = rr.ResourceId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] ur ON ur.RoleId = rr.RoleId  
    AND ur.UserId = '6BA60C09-2873-46A5-BAFB-5996A6C6482B'
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Resources r on r.id = xr.id 
WHERE xr.id IS NULL
```

I can't figure out a good strategy for this in `EF` because I don't have access to the association tables.

Can this be done in LINQ or lambda expression?

Comment: by the way, in what language do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have some sort of question but I will try to answer about your `query`

```
var y = (from xr in context.Resources
         join rr in context.x_Resource_RestrictedRole on xr.Id equals rr.ResourceId
         join ur in context.aspnet_UsersInRoles on rr.RoleId  equals ur.RoleId
         join r in context.Resources on xr.id equals r.id into rJoin
         from r2 in rJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where xr.id == null && ur.UserId = "6BA60C09-2873-46A5-BAFB-5996A6C6482B"
         select new { r.Name }).Distinct(c => c.Name).ToList();
```